# Filter a REST feature service by area or attribute with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-service, rest

I have access to a REST service that covers the entire United States with tens of thousands of individual polygon features.

Can I filter this down to a geographic region or a specific attribute?  As it is, I won't even load the layer.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the REST service. Please [Edit] the Question to contain additional details.

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'nature of the REST service" is, but I found if I right click on the layer in the contents pane, and then go to layer properties, I can specify attributes to filter with using the "Definition Query."

Comment: you can use polygon/envelope extents https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457607/querying-arcgis-rest-api-using-lat-long